# Android Studios: I cannot access method onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult), and it gives me an error when I try to override it on my own

Tags: java, android-studio, google-location-services

To preface, I am new to android development and android studios. I am trying to use Google APIs for Android, specifically Google Location and Activity Recognition, to display a device's current latitude and longitude coordinates.

I already included the dependency needed into the app `build.gradle` file: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0`

However, as I'm working on a `buildLocationCallback()` method, I tried to use keyboard shortcut Ctrl+O to bring up the "Select Methods to Override/Implement" window and it failed to bring up the method `onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult)`.

[image]

And when I try to override the method manually, it gives me errors

[image]

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: It's because you've added a semicolon to the line where you've created an instance of `LocationCallback` and hence your code will break. (See https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback for examples of how to use a `LocationCallback`)